# Drawing multiple rotated images next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw multiple rotated images next to each other on an HTML5 canvas, but unfortunately there's always a gap between them:

[image]

The idea is that I want to draw multiple blocks of different sizes using tiles. Each separate block can be rotates. When drawing such a block, I call the canvas's rotate function once to then draw all the tiles next to each other to form such a block.

At this point in time I don't really know what to do to solve the issue. Ofcourse I could use an offscreen canvas for each seperate block, but to my knowledge this will create some serious performance issues in my game since there can be a lot of these blocks, each with their own sizes, tiles and rotation.

Another option would be to use patterns, for this specific scenario that would be a viable option. But unfortunately I also need to draw blocks where the tiles on the edges get a [different image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzvm6.png).

What would be a good way to get rid of these gaps? Shall I just draw extra tiles in between to fill the gaps in a bit of an hacky way. Or is there an option I haven't thought of yet?

**Edit:**
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Oli414/oxap9fgr/2/ (It applies to drawing in general, not just images).

```
ctx.rotate(rotation * Math.PI / 180);
for (var i = 0; i < width; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < height; j++)
  {
        ctx.fillRect(i * tileSize, j * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: @Anubhav I've added a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps:

1.: Create a fillStyle with the image, using ctx.createPattern(Image, wrap), and set wrap as "repeat" (Don't forget to wait before the image loads.

2.: Instead of drawing each image in a separate drawImage call, just use ctx.fillRect(beginX, beginY, width, height). This also has a better performance for bigger tiles.

There shouldn't be any gaps between the images.

If you don't like this idea, then you could simply oversize the image by 1 pixel in each direction.

Comment: Yeah I just added 1 pixek to the right abd bottom of the squares and the lines disapleared

Comment: As stated in the question the usage of a pattern isn't really going to help here. Some blocks use a [different image](http://i.imgur.com/yg7abzK.png) on the sides of the blocks. Increasing the size still leaves a gap in some cases and ruines the quality.

Comment: @Oli414 then just do drawImage(image, yourX, yourY, yourWidth **+1**, yourHeight **+1**), ut works for me, and has almost no visual difference.

Comment: I might go with that, it will require a bit of extra logic so that it isn't larger on the sides but that shouldn't make to much of a difference. It doesn't feel like it's the best solution but I'll accept your answer for now.

Comment: @Oli414 1 pixel. One. I've never seen someone counting pixels.

Comment: I've tried it before and that 1 pixel does make a difference. Physics are involved and it simply looks odd if the collision box is ever so slightly smaller then what is actually drawn. And yes, users did complain about it.